# Feature request: Show bounty details in iOS app

Tags: feature-request, bounty, ios-app, popup

In the iOS app there is a banner at the bottom of bounty-set posts. Whence clicked, a popup similar to the one below is displayed.

[image: bounty popup]

Could the details of the bounty be included in the popup?

---

In this [bounty-set question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444430/how-to-get-a-word-under-cursor-using-javascript/), for example, the bounty details are:

> I don't like to wrap each answer in a span. It is a hack. The answer by Eyal looks good, but does not work in my case. ... [snip] ... I am looking for a serious way to solve this that will not in the future break. A solution to handle all cases.

This would be particularly nice to see in the iOS app, especially while traveling, since there is no other way to see this on the app.