# A fully featured Android/iOS app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, ios-app

I would like to see the same functionality that is available on the Stack Exchange websites also available on the mobile apps. I mostly only use the Android app when I'm away from a computer and curious about any rep changes or comments. The lack of functionality  keeps me from using it much more than that.

I'm not an advanced Android programmer, but I think (naively, I'm sure) that if you gave me the standard [6-8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/284743) I could make an app that has most all of the same functionality as the website. Is there a reason this has not been done? Are there technical hurdles that I don't know about? (I'm sure there are, but are they too difficult to overcome?) If the Stack Exchange staff are too busy to do it themselves, is open sourcing it an option? You would think if any community could make a decent app, we could.

I imagine this question must be a duplicate, but I couldn't find it. Here are some more specific questions that are related, though.

- [Why don't we have profile editor available on Android app?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250519/why-dont-we-have-profile-editor-available-on-android-app)
- [Allow us to vote to delete from the Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216962/allow-us-to-vote-to-delete-from-the-android-app)
- [Feature request: Show bounty details in iOS app](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296015/feature-request-show-bounty-details-in-ios-app)

[This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340649/why-was-this-answer-deleted-for-moderation-purposes-what-am-i-not-seeing-here?cb=1) is the recent question that caused me to ask here.

**Update**

- Don't take the 6-8 weeks literally. Read the [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/284743).
- Using the website from a web browser on the phone is a viable option. However, one thing I like about the app is I've found it generally usable in China without a VPN, whereas [the website not so much](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258288/use-of-ajax-googleapis-com-not-china-friendly).

Comment: Note that some of the features require changes in the Stack Exchange API as well.

Comment: @Glorfindel Who says a private/proprietary/internal/[whatever the right word is] API with more capabilities than [the public API](https://api.stackexchange.com/) can't be used by official apps?

Comment: Sure they can, but they won't for whatever reason.

Comment: Define **Fully featured**, you literally wan't everything to be in the app? Including Documentation and Jobs? Anyway, I would love to have hats in the app ;)

Comment: @Rolfツ, Sure, I'd love to have Documentation and Jobs be available in the app. I mean everything.

Comment: I suspect Windows mobile users are downvoting this... I can't think of another reason.

Comment: @T J: As a Windows Mobile user, that made me laugh. Thanks.

Comment: If you want an app that works exactly like the website, why don't you just launch your mobile device's browser and go to stackoverflow.com? (This is a serious question. Probably you'll answer that this has usability issues, but then the question is not about an Android app but about a more mobile-friendly website.)

Comment: I would argue against an app altogether. SO works pretty well on mobile, and being basically a content site, I believe it can be entirely implemented in terms of a small-screen compatible site.

Comment: *If you gave [someone] the standard 6-8 weeks [he] could make an app that has most all of the same functionality as the website* - I doubt that and I am in Android development.

Comment: @TsahiAsher There's already an app & site, this question is about *improving* that user experience.

Comment: @juergend Indeed, since 90% of all the sites functionality isn't even in the API. That would require A) a lot of work to get it in there, then B) expose all those screens in the app and C) make it perform as nicely as the site does.

Comment: To be honest, if you think you have the skills & can dedicate the time, why not do it yourself using the public API? Perhaps if the app is good enough (i.e, *very good*), it could be used far more than the official app.

Comment: @cybermonkey see [the first comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340664/a-fully-featured-android-ios-app?cb=1#comment427083_340664). The public API is missing some important things...

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it is necessary for SE to put in all that effort to create an app of something that is basically already there. Okay, the app certainly lacks a lot of functionality, but it is enough to perform the basic, as it was designed for.

Coding the API to give all the endpoints necessary to expose the functionality of the site, coding all the screens and flows, etc. will take a tremendous time. Certainly more than the *6-8 weeks* you think you can do it is. How much time do you think it took for SE to develop SO? How many developers? Guess you need a lot more developers than the current few that are part of the mobile team.

Let them use their money wisely: bring the key features to the app and leave it there. We don't need the entire site in the app.

---

**Recommended** read if you want to get to know one of the persons active on the mobile team on a very personal level and why the work stalled last year: [Why has Stack Exchange stopped working on the Android app?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272419/245360)

Comment: I wish they hadn't built apps in the first place, and instead improved the mobile site.

Comment: I just got notified of your comment from my mobile since the site doesn't support notifications. That is basically the only feature I would really miss. The mobile site will do the rest and could use some more love indeed.

Comment: No, I don't. But I do against wasting development time for something that has little benefit. @canon

Comment: Thanks for the link to the article. That helped a lot to put things in better perspective.